# Webscraping Indeed/linkedIn Jobs/ Google/Google Maps

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

Im looking for the best and most efficient solution how to scrape the following websites:

- Indeed.com
- LinkedIn Jobs
- Google Maps
- Google Search

Im using the Scrapingtool Octoparse at the moment, but im not very satisfied with the tool. Cloud Scraping which they offer fails very often, so i always have to scrape locally which is not very efficient. I need a Tool/programm/service that can scrape these Websites on a large scale and cloud based.

Are there any Tools you can recommend? I heard much about scrapy, beautiful soup and other tools where you need Python knowledge. I would take the time to learn these tools, but im not very sure whats the most efficent way.

Im glad if someone here could give me some advice :)

PS: Im a Recruiter and need the data for my candidates. Id like to scrape as much joblisting Plattforms as possible to collect all the companys who are hiring.

Answer (score 0):

The data you need to harvest does not come from linkedin. The data you need to harvest comes from your candidates. You need to place them where they belong, not where you can get them the soonest.

Comment: How do you interpret from the text that im not collecting any data from the candidates? Im trying to find matches between their jobwishes and conditions and the companys which provide these.

Comment: Very bad experience with recruiters.